# filtering sparql results before doing an arbitrairy path query

Tags: filter, path, sparql, rdf

To explain my question I will give a fruity example:

Let's say we have an RDF triple-store filled with 3 classes:

```
:Apple
:Orange
:Pear
```

And we have 1 property:

```
:friendsWith
```

Apples, oranges and pears can be friends with other apples, oranges and pears.
The query that I want to implement is:

"Given apple/123, give me all apples and pears with which apple/123 is friends through anything but oranges."

My current version of this SPARQL query looks like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?appleOrPear WHERE {
    <apple/123> :friendsWith* ?appleOrPear .
    FILTER NOT EXISTS {?appleOrPear a :Orange.}
}
```

This query does indeed give me only apples and pears that are connected to apple/123. However it would also give me apples and pears that are connected through oranges, which I don't want.

So what I need is a way for the results to be filtered before the arbitrairy path part of the query is done. In other words I want to ignore the whole :orange class for the entire query.

Is there any way to do this in SPARQL?

Comment: Sub SELECT query?

Comment: How would you use sub SELECT to solve this?
Could you give an example?

Answer (score 2):

You may check that there is no node of type `:Orange` in the `:friendsWith` chain between `<apple/123>` and `?appleOrPear`.

```
SELECT distinct ?appleOrPear WHERE {
    <apple/123> :friendsWith* ?appleOrPear .
    filter not exists {
        <apple/123> :friendsWith* ?x .
        ?x :friendsWith* ?appleOrPear .
        ?x a :Orange .
    }
}
```

Comment: Very nice idea.
This would almost work.
However this also removes entities that are reachable through both orange and non-orange paths.

Comment: Yes, it excludes all solutions where a path through an :Orange instance exists. Since there is no way to exclude particular :friendsWith relations based on the type of the subject/object during the computation of the path expression, the only other idea is to somehow flag/place only the relevant :friendsWith relations and query those. E.g. put all :friendsWith relations between instances only of :Apple and :Pear in separate context and lookup there or alternatively, use a different sub-property of :friendsWith that links only apples and pears.

Comment: Adding a different context is actually a viable option for the real-world problem that I try to solve, thank you very much Damyan.

I regret the fact though that SPARQL has limited possibilities for arbitrairy path queries, then again it's focus is not supporting path queries.